# Approximation to Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I know that the sum of independent 0-1 indicators with different success probabilities can be approximated by Possion distribution under certain conditions.  However, I want to know which conditions should hold where indicators are dependent. does anyone have information about the conditions for dependency case?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There is an excellent book about this: https://global.oup.com/academic/product/poisson-approximation-9780198522355?cc=us&lang=en&

Comment: @kimchilover thank you. I will check that.